# Stripping Characters from Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get just the team name and delete the team records which were attached when I scraped the table. I know I can use rstrip(), but I don't want to enter all of the team records to remove. Any ideas?

```
# Using Pandas to extract rankings tables

import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html(base_site)
# base_site = "http://cbssports.com/college-football/rankings/cbs-sports-ranking/"

rankings=tables[0]
rankings

rankings.drop(['Trend', 'Next Game', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 3'], axis=1)
```

from that I get:

```
    Rank    Team
0   1   LSU 15-0
1   2   Clemson 14-1
2   3   Ohio St. 13-1
3   4   Georgia 12-2
4   5   Oregon 12-2

...     ...     ...
125     126     New Mexico St. 2-10
126     127     Old Dominion 1-11
127     128     UTEP 1-11
128     129     Massachusetts 1-11
129     130     Akron 0-12
```

130 rows × 2 columns

Looking to remove the teams' records from the Teams column. Thoughts?

Comment: but I don't want to enter all of the team records to remove. Any ideas? not understanding this ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I would need to specify the characters or strings to strip which would be the team records: . ie rstrip(15-1, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `rsplit`

```
df['Team']=df['Team'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1).str[0]
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the n=1).strip(0) does? Thanks

Comment: @DJF rsplit ,split the string from the right , and only split the 1st blank, we get the first part